# 3ds max's dot ring in blender?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

Ok so I've pretty much done the move from 3ds max to blender as my everyday software, but there's a useful feature that's in max that I can't find in blender. It's the dot ring selection mode.

In the 3ds max modeling ribbon you can use dot ring to select a ring with gaps in it.
[image: Dot ring on a cylinder.]

It's a useful feature if, for whatever reason, you had to collapse a subdivision surface modifier, and you wanted to decimate it by hand while keeping the flow of the topology intact since you can select entire loops with a gap of 1 between them then delete.

The dot ring selection in action:
[image: The dot ring selection in action.]

Then delete selection.
[image: Then delete selection.]

Is there a similar feature in Blender ? If not can I request it ?
Thanks.

Comment: For extending an initially selected pair, to repeats of the interval between them , you might also want to look at Shit-Ctrl-Numpad+, 'Select Next Active'.

Comment: Thank you sir, that's pretty much what I needed !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest thing to this in blender is checker deselect. If that does not do what you want, yes, you can request such a feature. I do not know where to request features for blender, though.

Comment: How about [Select every other face loop](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjK5bbklcrwAhUCcBQKHVbAC2AQFjABegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblender.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F3487%2Fselect-every-other-face-loop&usg=AOvVaw0MUNvYCTvhJRhD0IoqCnNo)? - Look down the page to see the same for edge loops.

Comment: Thank you, it does the trick !

Comment: The forum for Blender suggestions is [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/)